# Any way to change the tag of error() in CActiveForm?

Tags: php, yii, html

By default, `CActiveForm::error()` display an error in `<div>` tag. Sometimes I want to use `<span>` tag instead of `<div>`, but it seems that the source code of this method has fixed using div tag only.

In CHtml::error():

```
return self::tag('div',$htmlOptions,$error);
```

So is there any method to change the tag without touching the framework's source code?

Comment: The only difference between a div and a span is that the span is an inline element. What about setting the display type to inline in htmloptions and applying a class to your div to achieve the same effect as your desired span element?

Comment: Yes, display:inline sounds right. But this won't solve my problem because my `errorMessage` is inside `<p>` (paragraph) tag.

Comment: yes and one little advice although its better or sometimes you should use an specific tag but always try to relay on css properties not html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically `CHtml::$errorContainerTag = 'span';` should do the trick.

And you can always override `CHtml::error(...)` method via child class (e.g. `class Html extends CHtml {...}`)